# SSAS 2012 - Dimension Modeling

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, ssas

I am working with a structure that results a lot of single attribute dimensions that require no hierarchy.  Examples:

- Status(Status Name)
- Type(Type Name)

I get the following warning when compiling the project:

**"Avoid having multiple dimensions containing a single attribute. Consider unifying them if possible."**

A large number of single attribute dimensions is workable for our users, but it causes a lot of clutter in the Excel pivot table.  Dimensions are listed along with the single attribute which is redundant.

[image: single attribute dimension]

I would like to unify them as the warning suggests so that I have a single dimension called 'Attributes' which contains status/type/etc, but I am unsure the best way to do so.  It doesn't make conceptual sense to me with a parent/child dimension.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll try a named query with unique key:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/06cea0ca-d8e9-4cf6-b83b-36970f900a2a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree this is a worthwhile change.  I would construct a view that brings together the required attributes.  Often they are all available on the fact/measure group table/view, so you can just use the same source object (in your DSV) to construct the dimension.

The tricky part may be the dimension key.  The most flexible key is a Fact Surrogate Key eg a unique value per Fact row - in the future you can add any other fact-based attributes without affecting the key.  However this will not scale indefinitely - you are probably OK up to 1m rows at least.

Beyond that scale, I would concatenate the attributes to form the dimension key and deliver them to a new dimension table.  I would normally do this back in the ETL layer. The identical concatenation logic must be used for both the dimension and fact.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This approach worked well.  My data is relatively small so the view with a fact key was a good solution.